# set position to "Count" in Flip Tile (live tile) for WP8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, live-tile

Can i set a custom position for the "Count" value in a Flip Tile Template ? If so , how ? please elaborate !
i am creating a Live Tile for my game , i want to use the Count option of the Flip Tile Template but would like to change the position of the Count Value to my desired location within the tile .
Any Help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change this position.  All the elements of a live tile are fixed in place and you an only change their values.